# what is the difference between request.ip and request.raw.ip in fastify?

Tags: fastify

Difference between request.ip and request.raw.ip in fastify.

Request
The first parameter of the handler function is Request.
Request is a core Fastify object containing the following fields:

raw - the incoming HTTP request from Node core
ip - the IP address of the incoming request

It contains more fields I am just showing relevant fields to my question.
you can check more field out here -> https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Request/

Comment: Are you meaning `request.raw.connection.remoteAddress`? since `request.raw.ip` does not exists

Comment: One of the packages of fastify namely fastify rate limit says that it exists 
please refer to this URL  -> https://github.com/fastify/fastify-rate-limit/#:~:text=req.raw.ip%20//%20fallback%20to%20default

Comment: The doc [is wrong, the code is right :)](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-rate-limit/blob/ce1d4e1ef12ba7d784d74655952fe08e79f43fed/index.js#L83)

Answer (score 4):

> Difference between request.ip and request.raw.ip in fastify.

There is a difference only if your server runs behind a proxy/balancer.

Let's make an example:

Client IP: 123.123.123.123
Balancer IP: 10.10.10.10

The `request.raw.connection.remoteAddress` will be `10.10.10.10`
The `request.ip` will be `123.123.123.123` (only if [`trustProxy`](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#trustproxy) option is enabled) or it will ba as the `raw` one

Many other ones are just shortcuts such as [`hostname`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/ae9074319a88f267459f2bc7a072410f85be2e42/lib/request.js#L155) or [`url`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/ae9074319a88f267459f2bc7a072410f85be2e42/lib/request.js#L111).

Ip example:

```
Runs locally the Fastify server
{"ip":"127.0.0.1","ipRaw":"","ipRemote":"127.0.0.1"}

Runs behind a ngnix with trust proxy (192.168.128.2 is nginx)
{"ip":"192.168.128.1","ipRaw":"","ips":["192.168.128.2","192.168.128.1"],"ipRemote":"192.168.128.2"}

Runs behind a ngnix without trust proxy (return the caller ip)
{"ip":"192.168.128.2","ipRaw":"","ipRemote":"192.168.128.2"}
```

You can play with it:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({
  logger: true,
  trustProxy: true
})

fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return {
    ip: request.ip,
    ipRaw: request.raw.ip || '',
    ips: request.ips,
    ipRemote: request.raw.connection.remoteAddress
  }
})

fastify.listen(5000, '0.0.0.0')
```

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    localnode:
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-fastify
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    nginx:
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
```

Fastify

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./proxy.js .
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "proxy.js"]
```

nginx

```
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 8080
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

and the config

```
server {
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://localnode:5000;
  }
}
```

PS: these docker files are not for production